# vba text to columns different results

Tags: excel, vba

I have a value, as a number which is recognized and viewable as 09/01/2022.

I've recorded a macro where I select a column and follow the process of  - Data - text to columns - delimited - unselect all - TEXT - finish.

This results in the viewable cell stating - 09/01/2022
this is what I was expecting.

However, when I run the recorded macro - on the same data set, same PC, the result is: 1/9/2022.

The recorded code that I play is -

```
Columns("X:X").Select
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("X1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
        :=Array(1, 2), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
```

Does anyone know why the format changes between performing the actions vs executing the macro on the same data set and how I can fix it.

Thanks,

Comment: `TextToColumns`, as you use it, only makes text the `Date` **as it is recognized by your system** according to the user localization. If you import that column from a (text/csv) file, you can set the import way to return that column as text, with the original format in the file where imported from...

Comment: I'm working from a report from a external party that I can't control. Is there a way to adapt the data for my needs. I'm really not understanding why the process works when I physically press the relevant buttons in excel vs when I run the macro.

Comment: Try reading carefully my above comment and understand it... The function you use only convert to text the Date as it was recognized by Excel, according to the regionalization settings. But if in that "report from a external party" the `Date` is kept as string, you can open it as I suggested above. Otherwise, each Excel will guess and appreciate the Date according to what I said before. `TextToColumns` cannot change anything from this point of view.

Comment: ok, so really then if there is no way to control the macro then the user will just have to execute this part manually - outside of any VBA as that part cannot be controlled. Unless there is a wok around to change the local settings then revert back to what they were originally.

Comment: It depends... what format have the Date in discussion in "the report from a external party"? Is it Date or text? What formula "=day(A2)" does return? Is it the same? If yes, it is only a matter of format, easy to  be corrected. Is it text? If so, you should open/import it in a different wey. I will show you how if you can  clarify this aspect.

Comment: oh, this is great fun. its a mix of text and date formats. But we established its in the mm/dd/yyyy format, in the most part. its just this 1 date format thing that seems to be the issue now. the rest of the logic works via a formula to convery it based of various different outputs.

Comment: "The most part" is not good enough... If not anything confidential, can you share that document? With dummy data in rest of the columns. Otherwise, there may exist problems in your computer, too.